# Show Gridview column total in Asp.net Label in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to show the `Gridview` column total in `Label` which is outside the `Gridview`. I wrote bellow function and call it on blur but for loop is not executed it doesn't enter in the for loop any help is apreciated thanks.

```
function footertotal() {
 var col1;
 var grid = 0;
 var totalcol1=0;
 grid = document.getElementById('<%=Grid1.ClientID %>');
  for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
   totalcol1 += parseFloat(Grid1.Rows[i].Cells['Tprice'].Value);
  }
 document.getElementById('<%=LblSubTotal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = totalcol1.toFixed(2).toString();
}
```

Comment: Could you show your aspx page to be sure of the `IDs`, please

Comment: Let us see the HTML output :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you are not using well the method `getElementById`.
You have to do like this:

```
function footertotal() {
     var col1;
     var totalcol1=0;
     var grid = document.getElementById('Grid1.ClientID');
     for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
      totalcol1 += parseFloat(Grid1.Rows[i].Cells['Tprice'].Value);
     }
document.getElementById('LblSubTotal.ClientID').innerHTML = totalcol1.toFixed(2).toString();

  }
```

For more help you can have a look here: [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)